# iOS - How to show a bar under navigation bar?

Tags: ios

My app have a navigation bar on the top, and a tab bar on botton, over a mapview. I need a way to filter some pins of the mapview. So, i`m trying to add a bar or something like that, under the navigation bar.

http://localhostr.com/file/gjjMqN4/Captura%20de%20Tela%202012-02-02%20s%2011.18.46.png

This bar will have 2 text views and a button to perform the filtering job.
I need this bar to be retractile by pressing a button on my navigation bar.

If I run the project that way i get this:

http://localhostr.com/file/TfqlFnW/Captura%20de%20Tela%202012-02-02%20s%2011.22.07.png

The bar is floating in the wrong place. =s

I`m making it right? Or can I make it in another 'best' way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have an IBOutlet to the toolbar in your controller, and once the view is loaded, e.g. `viewDidLoad`, adjust its coordination, i.e. x and y to hide it.
Then, you can add a `UIBarButtonItem` that when triggered, it calls a toggle method to show or hide the toolbar, e.g.

> ```
> - (IBAction)toggleToolbar {
>  if (toolbar.isInView)
>     [self hideToolbar];
>  else
>     [self showToolbar];
> }
>
> - (void) hideToolbar {
> // implementation to hide the toolbar
> }
>
> - (void) showToolbar {
> // implementation to show the toolbar
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

without a bit of code is difficult to say where you're wrong. In the meantime, I suggest another solution: add a barbuttonitem to the navigationbar that open a modal view where you can put the two thextfield and the button; so you have more space for the map e graphically is more "attractive".